# web api controller calling issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

Hi all I have written the following code when user clicks on sign in

```
function login() {
        var Emp = {};
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        Emp.userID = username;
        Emp.ppassword = password;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"<%=Page.ResolveUrl("/api/Login/")%>",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(Emp),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert('Inserted');
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                alert(x.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

My controller is structured as follows
[image]

This is my webapiconfig code

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

controller code

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;

    private bool CheckLogin(string userID, string password)
    {
        bool bFlag = false;
        con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("uspGetUserDetails", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@return", SqlDbType.Int);
        parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", userID));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", password));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(parm.Value);
        return bFlag;
    }
}
```

But on clicking login I am getting an error as `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request` so can some one help me where I went wrong

Comment: where is your controller has single parameter method? in your 'DefaultApi' configuration only one optional parameter you defined.

Comment: If `CheckLogin` is meant to be your `GET` action/endpoint (as your ajax call suggests), then either call it `GetCheckLogin` or decorate it with the `[HttpGet]` attribute. Also, make sure it's public, not private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you send should match the action method parameters names. So if it's not typo rename `Emp.ppassword = password` to -> `Emp.password = password` with single **'p'** in the begining.

Also if you want your action method to be visible to internet make it public

```
public bool CheckLogin(string userID, string password)
{
    // ...
}
```